# "You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type" after installing react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I am very new in React and trying to add a simple map in web application. But right after installing react-leaflet (`npm install react react-dom leaflet, npm install react-leaflet`), I try to import `MapContainer`, etc:

```
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet'
```

After import, as soon as I run npm start I get this error message:

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code you have so far...

Comment: Exactly which part of the code do you need? I mean the code is so big...

Comment: The part of the code that the error comes from

Comment: I have edited the question. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I think it has to do with your webpack configuration or any other bundler you are using

Comment: Where is webpack file located in React?  Do you know it is full name and path?

Comment: if you use create-react-app it should be preconfigured for  you, but if you don't then you might have implemented wrong configuration